# Remembering old data

Tags: loops, haskell, state

Remembering your first time (in a Haskell loop)

I am trying to teach myself a little Haskell by going through some Hackerrank questions.

The question I am looking at involves reading in sets of co-ordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and
Determining the perimeter of the polygon drawn by those co-ordinates.

Here is my code so far:

```
-- Calculate length of line given points x1,y2, x2,y2
calc_length:: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Float 
calc_length x1 y1 x2 y2 =
       sqrt ( fromIntegral (height ^2 + width ^2)  )
       where height = abs( y2 - y1) 
             width  = abs( x2 - x1) 


main = do
        x <- readLn :: IO Double
        forM_ [1,2..(x / 2)] $ \lc -> do
           line1 <- getLine
           let wds1 = map (\str -> read str::Int) (words $ line1)
           line2 <- getLine
           let wds2 = map (\str -> read str::Int) (words $ line2)
           print ( wds1, wds2)
```

The problem I have is that I need to calculate the distance between the first and last co-ordinates I.e. REMEMBER the first pair of numbers entered ( stored in line1). But after multiply iterations the first pair will be lost. I have tried using global variables to store the first calling of getLine (with little success, and even if that had worked I don’t it think it would help.)

I get the feeling that there is a more functional approach I could try but just don’t know how.

I am not looking for a full coded solution just an approach that points me in a better direction.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you simply store all coordinates (in a list)? Just change `forM_` to `forM` and `print` to `return`.

Comment: Hi Melpomene, ok looks like i need to investigate forM_ vs formM - I see that formM allows me to remember results whereas forM_ doestn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to treat the first iteration differently, it should be separated (if I understand your problem correctly). You can reduce duplication by using a helper function:

```
getNumLine :: IO [Int]
getNumLine = do
    line <- getLine
    return (map read (words line))

main = do
    x <- readLn :: IO Int   -- Double seemed wrong, use integer `div` below instead
    firstline <- getNumLine
    forM_ [2..x `div` 2] $ \lc -> do
        ...
```

And yes you could be much more "functional" about this, but I think it's best to learn in baby steps.

Answer (score 5):

You asked for a more functional way of thinking about this, so I'm going to try to provide that. You said you're new to Haskell, so I apologize in advance if this touches on things you haven't explored yet. Feel free to ask for clarification in any part of it.

First off, let's segment your `calcLength` function a bit more. We're passing it two points, so rather than passing four arguments, let's pass only two.

```
data Point a = Point a a

calcLength :: Floating a => Point a -> Point a -> a
calcLength (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2) = sqrt (height ^ 2 + width ^ 2)
    where height = abs (y2 - y1)
          width  = abs (x2 - x1)
```

Now let's write a function that reads a single point. We'll call this from `main` rather than reading two numerical values separately in `main`.

```
readPoint :: (Floating a, Read a) => IO (Point a)
readPoint = Point <$> readLn <*> readLn
```

I'm using applicative syntax here. If you're more familiar with do-notation, the equivalent would be

```
readPoint :: (Floating a, Read a) => IO (Point a)
readPoint = do
  x <- readLn
  y <- readLn
  return $ Point x y
```

Now for the meat of your question. We want to take a list of things (points in your case) and produce adjacent pairs, making sure to loop around to the beginning. Let's stop thinking about it in terms of points for a moment and just write a function that works on *any* list of things.

```
-- We're going to take a list of things and produce a list of pairs of those things
loopedPairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
-- If the original list is empty, return the empty list
loopedPairs [] = []
-- Otherwise, start recursing
loopedPairs (x:xs) = go x xs
    -- Here, we're pairing off all the elements
    where go x' (y:ys) =  (x', y) : go y ys
          -- Because we defined this as an inner function, we can still access
          -- the original first element, effectively "remembering" it like you
          -- were asking about. Note that we never use any "global" storage or
          -- mutable state to do this, just a bit of variable scope.
          go x' []     = [(x', x)]
```

Now we'll write a perimeter function. It's good to separate as much of your "pure" non-IO logic from the IO work as possible, so we want to factor this out of `main`.

```
newtype Polygon a = Polygon [Point a]

perimeter :: Floating a => Polygon a -> a
perimeter (Polygon xs) = sum . map (\(a, b) -> calcLength a b) $ loopedPairs xs
```

We take a polygon, which is really just a list of points, pair off all of our points using `loopedPairs`, then calculate the length between each of them and sum the results.

With that in mind, `main` is fairly short.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  n <- readLn :: IO Int
  points <- replicateM n (readPoint :: IO (Point Double))
  let result = perimeter (Polygon points)
  print result
```

We read in the number of points, then we read each point (`replicateM` essentially means "do this thing `n` times and accumulate the result into a list). Then we calculate the perimeter and print it out.

Runnable solution:

```
import Control.Monad

data Point a = Point a a

newtype Polygon a = Polygon [Point a]

calcLength :: Floating a => Point a -> Point a -> a
calcLength (Point x1 y1) (Point x2 y2) = sqrt (height ^ 2 + width ^ 2)
    where height = abs (y2 - y1)
          width  = abs (x2 - x1)

readPoint :: (Floating a, Read a) => IO (Point a)
readPoint = Point <$> readLn <*> readLn

loopedPairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
loopedPairs [] = []
loopedPairs (x:xs) = go x xs
    where go x' (y:ys) =  (x', y) : go y ys
          go x' []     = [(x', x)]

perimeter :: Floating a => Polygon a -> a
perimeter (Polygon xs) = sum . map (\(a, b) -> calcLength a b) $ loopedPairs xs

main :: IO ()
main = do
  n <- readLn :: IO Int
  points <- replicateM n (readPoint :: IO (Point Double))
  let result = perimeter (Polygon points)
  print result
```

I invite you to dissect this, and let me know if you have any questions at all. Functional programming is a tricky mindset to get into, because it's very different from other programming, but it's a handy set of techniques to have in your toolbelt.

Comment: Hi Silvio, thank you for taking the time to provide a really comprehensive response. Appreciate your efforts. I am certain there is much I can learn from your code. Which I will spend some time looking at.

Answer (score 0):

After everbodys help: my final solution:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Traversable
import Data.List.Split

          -- Calculate length of line given points x1,y2, x2,y2
          calc_length:: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Float 
         calc_length x1 y1 x2 y2 =
               sqrt ( fromIntegral (height ^2 + width ^2)  )
               where height = abs( y2 - y1) 
                     width  = abs( x2 - x1)


        -- Calculate the distances between vertex points (except the last)
        getResults list = 
            sum [ calc_length (head f)  (last f) (head s)  (last s)   |  (f,s)  <-  (zip list (tail list)) ]  


       -- Calculate the last vertex distance between points
       headAndTail list =
           calc_length (z!!0) (z!!1) (z!!2) (z!!3)
           where z  = head list ++ last list 

        -- Prompt the user for co-ordinate pairs
        main = do
                x <- readLn :: IO Double
                result <- forM [1,2..x ] ( \lc -> do
                   line1 <- getLine
                   let wds1 = map (\str -> read str::Int) (words $ line1)
                   return wds1)

                print (  (getResults result) + (headAndTail result)   )
```